# Replace Symbols with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im looking for function that will allow me to remove (replace) all symbols in my body tag apart from a-z letter.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: can you maybe give an example because there are a few interpretations of your question / not sure if you mean the <body> tag itself or the entire body innerHTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var new_body = $('body').html().replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');
```